# Error on validation if dropdown is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

My form is:

```
            <%= form_for @setup_limo, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
            <%= render 'Partials/errors', object: @setup_limo %>
              <div class="control-group">
                <%= f.label :car_type_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls">
                  <%= f.collection_select :car_type_id,CarType.all,:id,:name, :class => 'text_field' %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <%= f.label :car_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls">
                  <%= f.collection_select :car_id,Car.all,:id,:name, :class => 'text_field' %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <%= f.label :driver_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls">
                  <%= f.collection_select :driver_id,Driver.all,:id,:name, :class => 'text_field' %>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-actions">
                <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
                <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                            setup_limos_path, :class => 'btn' %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
```

My Model is:

```
    class SetupLimo < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :car_type
      belongs_to :car
      belongs_to :driver


        validates :user,:car_type,:car, :driver, :presence => :true

        validates_uniqueness_of :driver, :scope =>[:user, :car_type, :car]
    end
```

My controller permitted params:

```
        def setup_limo_params
          params.require(:setup_limo).permit(:car_type_id, :car_id, :driver_id, :user_id)
        end
```

Create action:

```
      def create
        @setup_limo = SetupLimo.new(setup_limo_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @setup_limo.save
            format.html { redirect_to @setup_limo, notice: 'Setup limo was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @setup_limo }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @setup_limo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

But on create i got error: The log is:

```
            Started POST "/setup_limos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-09 21:02:05 +0530
            Processing by SetupLimosController#create as HTML
              Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"######=", "setup_limo"=>{"car_type_id"=>"3", "driver_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Setup limo"}
              [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
              [1m[36mCarType Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `car_types`.* FROM `car_types` WHERE `car_types`.`id` = 3 ORDER BY `car_types`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
              [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  ROLLBACK
            Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 482ms

            NoMethodError (undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass):
              app/controllers/setup_limos_controller.rb:35:in `block in create'
              app/controllers/setup_limos_controller.rb:34:in `create'


              Rendered /Users/MohammedSha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.1ms)
              Rendered /Users/MohammedSha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.7ms)
              Rendered /Users/MohammedSha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.0ms)
              Rendered /Users/MohammedSha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (42.6ms)
```

I'm using Rails 4
On submitting i got the above error,
I want to validate uniqueness of driver for user, car_type and car
Thanks for any help..

Comment: please show us your `create` action in `setup_limos_controller.rb`

Comment: @ Pierre-Louis Gottfrois added the create method, (i've edited and added it in my question)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something in the description, but you have a `presence` validation on driver and it is empty in the passed params.

If a driver can be empty, then drop it from that validation on `SetupLimo`:

```
validates :user, :car_type, :car, :presence => :true
```

Comment: No the driver cant be empty, i want the driver from dropdown.